# Creating a sequence inside an anonymous block using Execute Immediate

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, execute-immediate

I'm trying to create a sequence inside an anonymous block (it's an script that will be launched on several environments) and I'm using execute immediate, this is the code:

```
SELECT MAX(ID_VINCULACION)
INTO vMAX_VINCULACION
FROM SA_ENTIDADES_VINCULADAS;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "GPP"."SEQ_ENTIDADES_VINCULADAS" MINVALUE 1  MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH ' || vMAX_VINCULACION || ' NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE NOKEEP NOSCALE GLOBAL';
```

I'm using the select max for start with so i can get the biggest existing ID, but it is throwing this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
> ORA-06512: at line 40
> ORA-06512: at line 40

I don't exactly know why, so I tried to use the Execute Immediate ... Using, this is the resulting code:

```
SELECT MAX(ID_VINCULACION)
    INTO vMAX_VINCULACION
    FROM SA_ENTIDADES_VINCULADAS;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE "GPP"."SEQ_ENTIDADES_VINCULADAS" MINVALUE 1  MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH :a NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE NOKEEP NOSCALE GLOBAL' USING vMAX_VINCULACION;
```

And this one throws another error... :

> ORA-01722: invalid number

I don't get this one either, as the Max function returns a number. I have tried launching the query and it returns a 5.

So I'm pretty lost here, hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is intended for statements without parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute immediate is evaluated at runtime. I did a test and it works without issues ( in my test I remove double quotes, because you don't need them ). Try to print by `dbms_output` the result of the `execute immediate`. Probably your select max is not giving you the right number.

**UPDATE**

The options `NOKEEP NOSCALE GLOBAL` are not available in 10g

[Create Sequence 10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20sequence%20in%20another%20user%27s%20schema%2C%20you%20must,CREATE%20ANY%20SEQUENCE%20system%20privilege.&text=Specify%20the%20schema%20to%20contain,sequence%20in%20your%20own%20schema.&text=Specify%20the%20name%20of%20the%20sequence%20to%20be%20created.)

```
declare
v_max pls_integer;
begin
   SELECT 1000 INTO v_max FROM dual;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ MINVALUE 1  MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '||v_max||' 
                   NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE NOKEEP NOSCALE GLOBAL' ;
end;
/
```

Test

```
SQL> declare
v_max pls_integer;
   begin
    SELECT 1000 INTO v_max FROM dual;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ MINVALUE 1  MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '||v_max||'
                    NOCACHE NOORDER NOCYCLE NOKEEP NOSCALE GLOBAL' ;
end;
/  

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select sequence_name, min_value, max_value from dba_sequences where sequence_name = 'MY_SEQ' ;

SEQUENCE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE
---------- ----------
MY_SEQ
         1 1.0000E+26


SQL> SQL> select my_seq.nextval from dual ;

   NEXTVAL
----------
      1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you said and removed the double quotes. I also tried the dbms_ouput from the max and is returning a 5 and also used dbms_ouput to see how the execute would look like: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE SEQUENCE GPP.SEQ_ENTIDADES_VINCULADAS
  MINVALUE 1 
  MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999999 
  INCREMENT BY 1 
  START WITH 5 
  NOCACHE 
  NOORDER 
  NOCYCLE 
  NOKEEP 
  NOSCALE 
  GLOBAL

And still throws the first error, ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended

Comment: if you run this command without using PLSQL, does it work ? I mean , it should work

Comment: Ok, tried what you said and with a little test I think I saw the problem. I have to remove the last three parameteres when creating the sequence: NOKEEP, NOSCALE and GLOBAL. Don't know why but it works this way. 
Thanks for you help man.

Comment: @robexpo, can you upvote the answer ? by the way, which version of Oracle are you using ? my test was done in 19c

Comment: you are welcome. Indeed, that is the reason. those options are not available in that old version. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20sequence%20in%20another%20user's%20schema%2C%20you%20must,CREATE%20ANY%20SEQUENCE%20system%20privilege.&text=Specify%20the%20schema%20to%20contain,sequence%20in%20your%20own%20schema.&text=Specify%20the%20name%20of%20the%20sequence%20to%20be%20created.

Comment: I would also get rid of `MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1` and anything else that is already the default value for any new sequence, as it's just taking up space and adding needless complication.